# Port forwarding multiple domains

Tags: networking

How do I port forward two TLD's to two separate nodes on my network. I've seem to have forgotten how to accomplish this.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. It doesn't mean anything to "forward" a "TLD". Are you talking about HTTP requests? Are you talking about DNS? It's really hard to figure out what you're asking. Do the machines you are forwarding to have public IP addresses? Are you doing the forwarding on a UNIX machine?

Comment: Let me reword this. I have TLD's pointing to my public IP. I need to point each one of those TLD's to two private IP's on my network. It matters not which one points to which. I just need to be able access both computers over the 0.0.0.0 spectrum. How do I accomplish this on a Windows machine or a D-Link router?

Comment: Are you talking about forwarding HTTP traffic? If so, you need a reverse proxy.

Comment: You can't. The router doing the NAT doesn't care what DNS resolution process took place on a client for that client to start sending data to the public IP, so would have no way of knowing which private IP to send it to. What protocol are you talking about forwarding? Which port? *edit* if it's HTTP, David's right - a reverse proxy would accomplish this.

Comment: @David Put that in an answer

Comment: Okay cool... Guess I'll consult Google for reverse proxies... Aw man I haven't done any real networking related tasks in awhile. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about forwarding HTTP traffic (web requests), you need to run a reverse proxy. If you're talking about almost any other protocol, there's no way to do it.

For most protocols, the client uses the domain name to figure out what IP address to connect to and doesn't do anything else with it. So unless the two domain names point to different IP addresses, there is no way to tell which one the client was asking about. HTTP is an exception, because it has a 'Host' header that tells you what name the client originally attempted to connect to.

Comment: Yep, it's HTTP. I've got an Apache server on each node. So how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Apache can do it with the [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) option. Use it inside a `Location` directive.